# Which framework for wireless sensor networks

Tags: omnet++, mixim

I want to develop and test a protocol for wireless sensor networks in OMNeT++. Which framework should I use? 
Is it sensible to use Castalia or MiXiM although they are deprecated?
Is it sensible to use inet without using the 802.11 stuff?

Comment: Framework* and we don't suggest software or frameworks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INET is practically a superset of MiXiM. It is possible to use it without the 802.11 radio. Depending on how accurate your physical model needs to be, you can configure it with different radios (with different speed and complexity). If your goal is to test routing algorithms then probably a simple radio will do the job. I also suggest to check out the wireless tutorial for INET.